# What's a good way to implement Yes/No menus in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working with some ASP.NET Core 3.1 code where a form has dozens of Y/N menus like this:

```html
<div class="form-group" id="Q3_2_div">
    <label>@Questions.Q3_2*</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answers.Q3_2, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo))),
        "Select One",
         new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Answers_Q3_2" })
</div>
```

Some of the Y/N menus look like this:

```html
<label>@Questions.Q140*</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answers.Q140,
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(YesNo)).OfType<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x), Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(YesNo), x) }), 
        "Value", "Text", YesNo.No),
    null, 
    new { @class = "custom-select", @id = "Answers_Q140" })
```

"Yes/No" is defined elsewhere:

```
public enum YesNo
{
    [Display(Name = "Yes")] Yes,
    [Display(Name = "No")] No
}
```

Is there a simpler, less verbose syntax I can use instead?  For example, could [tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper) are how I would do it.

My version would probably look something like this:

```
<select asp-for="Answers.Q140">
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Clean, simple, effective.

Comment: So no "custom tag helper": just the [OOTB](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OOTB) "asp-for" on the HTML "<select>", correct?  Q: This would work OK for my "Create" form.  But for my "Edit" form, how would I make the *current* value of "Answers.Q140" the "default" option?

Comment: That's correct, no need for a custom tag helper. The "asp-for" syntax will make the current value of "Answers.Q140" the "default" option. The code I have provided will accomplish this for you.

Comment: Perfect. I also confirmed: 1) If the model is non-nullable (e.g. `public bool Q140 { get; set; }`, then the tag helper will automagically add "required field" validation to the "select" element; 2) for my "Create" form, I can mark any option "selected" to make it the default; and 3) As you said, the tag helper will automagically mark the current value "selected" in my "Edit" form.  Good stuff - thank you!